# Invert a hexadecimal color in Android

Tags: java, android, colors, hex

How to invert a hexadecimal color in Android?
I am trying to use ~ but this invert alpha also.

```
 private PaintType getNegativePaintType(String hexa) {
    //hexa = "#28cb43"; 
    return new SolidColor(~Color.parseColor(hexa));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
private PaintType getNegativePaintType(String hexa) {
    //hexa = "#28cb43";
    int color = Color.parseColor(hexa);
    return new SolidColor((color & 0xFF000000) | (~color & 0x00FFFFFF));
}
```

The point is to cut off the inverted alpha value (`~color & 0x00FFFFFF`) and then apply (`|`) the original (`color & 0xFF000000`).

Or this:

```
private PaintType getNegativePaintType(String hexa) {
    //hexa = "#28cb43";
    int color = Color.parseColor(hexa);
    int invertedColor = ~color;
    return new SolidColor(Color.argb(Color.alpha(color), Color.red(invertedColor), Color.green(invertedColor), Color.blue(invertedColor)));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
`~cor.intValue() | 0xFF000000`

Comment: What's `cor`? What is its data type?

Comment: cor is an `int` value

Comment: `cor` is an `int`? I don't think `int` has a `intValue()` method since it's just a primitive.